# Connectors become disconnected from buttons after closing & reopening Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, button, shapes

I have an Excel file and a VBA macro that generates 2 buttons and puts a connector between them.The issue I encountered is that after I close the Excel file and reopen it, the connector is no longer connected to the buttons.

I noticed that the problem does not occur when I replace the buttons by simple rectangles. So I suspect that the way I connect the connectors to the buttons via `ShapeRange.Item(1)` might be incorrect. But I do not know any other way.

```
Sub CreateStuff()

Dim btn(1 To 2) As Button
Set btn(1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(50, 50, 100, 200)
Set btn(2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(300, 300, 150, 150)

Dim newConnector As Object
Set newConnector = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, 0, 100, 100)

With newConnector
 .ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect btn(1).ShapeRange.Item(1), 1
 .ConnectorFormat.EndConnect btn(2).ShapeRange.Item(1), 3
End With

End Sub




Sub TestConnection()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To .Count
        If .Item(i).Connector Then
            If .Item(i).ConnectorFormat.BeginConnected And .Item(i).ConnectorFormat.EndConnected Then
                MsgBox "Connection present"
            Else
                MsgBox "No Connection"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, and I am afraid that's an Excel bug (same happens when you create the connector manually in Excel). My advice would be to switch to shapes (I almost never use buttons). Alternative is to reconnect the buttons with a connector (or delete and recreate the connectors) with a macro that runs on Worksheet-Open.